# how to update the duplicate records counts serieswise (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get a duplicate data’s count from column 1 and same need to be updated in column 2 series wise. Require result like below.

```
  Column1   column 2        
*******************        
    Arun      1 
    Arun      2        
    Arun      3        
    Kumar     1        
    kumar     2        
    kumar     3        
    kumar     4        
    selva     1        
    velu      1
```

Comment: Please add some SQL that you tried and then others will love to help further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple ROW_NUMBER() should work fine for you. Use this:

```
SELECT Column1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column1) Column2
FROM YourTable;
```